# Throttling while registering activities in Simple Work Flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

We have started to experience failures when our processes start up during the registration of activities. The problem is happening in GenericActivityWorker.registerActivityTypes.

The exception generate is:

```
Caused by: AmazonServiceException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonSimpleWorkflow, AWS Request ID: 78726c24-47ee-11e3-8b49-534d57dc0b7f, AWS Error Code: ThrottlingException, AWS Error Message: Rate exceeded
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:350)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:202)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.invoke(AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java:3061)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.registerActivityType(AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient.java:2231)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericActivityWorker.registerActivityType(GenericActivityWorker.java:153)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericActivityWorker.registerActivityTypes(GenericActivityWorker.java:118)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericActivityWorker.registerTypesToPoll(GenericActivityWorker.java:105)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericWorker.start(GenericWorker.java:367)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.ActivityWorker.start(ActivityWorker.java:248)
    at com.fluid.retail.workflows.DefaultWorkflowHost.start(DefaultWorkflowHost.java:226)
    ... 5 more
```

The ActivityWorker in question has 5 activity implementation classes associated with it, and I think that this throttling is occurring because the internal Flow Framework code is looping over the activity types to register them without any delay in between them.

Because this code is internal to the framework, we can't add any sleep() calls to prevent being throttled.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=227326&tstart=0 that contains long discussion about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is happening during registering your ur activities? Or it is happening during scheduling your activities? 
You would get this issue if you try to run a workflow that will schedule too many activities too fast. At this point you have 2 options. 
1. Try and make the activites sequential and make them wait on the previous one. 
2. Contact AWS to increase your accounts rate.